# Identity Server 4 asp.net 2.1 - IProfileService or alternative

Tags: security, identityserver4, multi-tenant, openid-connect

***I will buy anyone a beer who can solve my problem!***

As a piece of work I need to update our Identity Server to use an implicit login flow, it was currently using Bearer Token access only. As a part of our architecture we are using Multi-tenancy.

For security reaosns we need to check the tenant header to verify that the user is not impersonating another tenant. To do this from a **client** perspective we use a custom IProfileService. This gets triggered in the middleware of Identity Server, meaning all is good!

However if I was a user and I wanted to use some form of functionality on Identity Server itself and not an actual client of it, then IProfileService will not be triggered. An example of this would be to revoke access to clients, or even log out.

*The GetProfileDataAsync Method on IProfileService is Invoked when the client request additional claims for the user.*

germansak on Github Issue here had a similar issue and it was never quite answered (https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1643)

**Leading to my question**, how has anyone been able to verify a Tenant on Identity Server itself when they are not going through a Client, but instead Identity Server. If I can't trigger IProfileService I feel as if I'm beat!

Answer (score 0):

Both logout and grants functionality is not part of the identity server 4 core package and they are simply implemented as ASP.NET Core razor views outside of the oauth2 flows.

There are few ways to validate headers therefore, I guess the easiest in my opinion would be to add another middleware.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<TenantHeaderValidationMiddleware>();
    ...Your other config
}

public class TenantHeaderValidationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RequestCultureMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        string tenantId = Request.Headers["YourTenantIdHeader"];
        //do the checking
        ...Validation logic
        //pass request further if correct
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```